# How can you escape quotes in form post submit?

Tags: php, html

For my form submission, whenever there is a single quote or double quote, all the text after the quote gets cut off in the $_POST['p#'] that is being sent. I have tried htmlspecialchars, string replacing with $#039, and addslashes but the string in the $_POST array still gets cut off. Here is the relevant part of the code and when $ques has a string with a single quote in it, there are problems.

```
        "<form action="some.php" method="post"><input type='checkbox' name='p".$numberOfProgrammingQuestion."' value='".$ques."'>".$ques."<br><br>";
```

Comment: it will be just guessing here without seeing your php code that handles it. can you post it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what is there the following should work....

```
"<form action="some.php" method="post"><input type='checkbox' name='p".$numberOfProgrammingQuestion."' value='".htmlspecialchars($ques, ENT_QUOTES)."'>".htmlspecialchars($ques, ENT_QUOTES)."<br><br>";
```

Notice the html special char flag ENT_QUOTES.  Documentation for it reads....

```
int
$flags
[optional]
A bitmask of one or more of the following flags, which specify how to handle quotes, invalid code unit sequences and the used document type. The default is ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401.
Available flags constants
Constant Name
Description
ENT_COMPAT
Will convert double-quotes and leave single-quotes alone.
ENT_QUOTES
Will convert both double and single quotes.
ENT_NOQUOTES
Will leave both double and single quotes unconverted.
ENT_IGNORE
Silently discard invalid code unit sequences instead of returning an empty string. Using this flag is discouraged as it may have security implications.
ENT_SUBSTITUTE
Replace invalid code unit sequences with a Unicode Replacement Character U+FFFD (UTF-8) or &#38;#FFFD; (otherwise) instead of returning an empty string.
ENT_DISALLOWED
Replace invalid code points for the given document type with a Unicode Replacement Character U+FFFD (UTF-8) or &#38;#FFFD; (otherwise) instead of leaving them as is. This may be useful, for instance, to ensure the well-formedness of XML documents with embedded external content.
ENT_HTML401
Handle code as HTML 4.01.
ENT_XML1
Handle code as XML 1.
ENT_XHTML
Handle code as XHTML.
ENT_HTML5
Handle code as HTML 5.
```

Comment: I don't think the problem here is actually around encoding of characters, but rather the fact that the poor way in which the OP was constructing the output string was causing the data he was trying to pre-populate into the input elements to be broken.

Comment: I was using htmlspecialchars($ques) before and overlooked that there were more parameters that could be used to make it work better. It works perfectly now, thanks Will!

Comment: I should have worded or showed only the input line of code to focus more on the actual problem I was having since the code must have made people misunderstand where the problem was, sorry about that Mike.

Answer (score 1):

You life will be much better if you use double and single quotes in a consistent fashion. Typically you should ALWAYS use double quotes around HTML element property values. This is pretty much an industry standard.

So keeping that in mind, I typically like to use single quotes when echoing out HTML elements in PHP.  And I just use long-form concetenation to it is very clear where I am putting in dynamic values.  This also prevents need to worry about escaping quotes.

My suggestion would be to alter you code as follows:

```
echo '<form action="some.php" method="post"><input type="checkbox" name="p' . $numberOfProgrammingQuestion . '" value="' . $ques . '">' . $ques . '<br><br>';
```

Note the even using StackOverflow's rudimentary syntax highlighting how clear it is to see where the static string is and where the dynamic values are. Compare that to the syntax highlighting in your original post.  You can see how your inconsistent use of double and single quotes is problematic.

So my suggestion, as you learn, would be to work in an editor with good syntax highlighting capabilities. This will help guide you through some of these issues.

Comment: My problem is not that. I just copy and pasted the code I showed above wrong. The issue was that the string contained in $ques sometimes has single quotes which cuts off everything after the quote when the form is submitted through POST. The php that receives the POST receives every UP UNTIL the first single quote (not including).

Comment: @Garvin Yes that is because you put used single quotes around your value like `value='XXXXX'`  Such that if you have a `'` in your value itself you would get `value='XXX'XXX'` and only the first part would be captured.  Now you certainly would need to encode double quotes in this scenario.